# C# - Doesn't add an element to the first empty array's index

Tags: c#, arrays, null, element, addition

Hi I'm currently working on a schoolproject where we have to add sodas to a sodacrate. I'm new to programming just so you guys know. I encountered a problem I can't solve. When I for example add 3 sodas at the arrays index 0,1 and 2 and later remove the element at perhaps index 1. If I then go back to adding sodas, it doesn't add a soda to index 1 and continue on index 3.
Sorry, I don't know any other way to explain this problem.
If you notice any other problems it I would very grateful if you could point them out!

Thanks in advance!

```
class Soda
{
    private string name;
    private int price;
    private string type;

    public Soda(string _name, int _price, string _type)
    {
        name = _name;
        price = _price;
        type = _type;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }    

    public int Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    public string Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }

}

class Sodacrate
{
    private Soda[] sodas = new Soda[25];
    private Soda[] content = new Soda[10];
    private int amount_bottles = 0;

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        int alternatives;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-=Sodacrate-Simulator=-");
            Console.WriteLine("\n===========");
            Console.WriteLine("HUVUDMENY");
            Console.WriteLine("===========\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Välj alternativ");
            Console.WriteLine("------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] Lägg till dryck i Läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] Skriv ut innehållet i läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] Beräkna det totala värdet av läskbacken");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] Sök efter dryck");
            Console.WriteLine("[5] Avsluta programmet\n");
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    alternatives = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Ogiltigt val");
                }
            }

            switch (alternatives)
            {
                case 1: add_soda();
                    break;
                case 2: print_crate();
                    break;
                case 3: calc_total();
                    break;
                case 4: find_soda();
                    break;
                case 5: Console.WriteLine("Programmet avslutas...");
                    break;
                default: Console.WriteLine("Felaktig inmatning"); Console.Clear();
                    break;
            }

        } while (alternatives != 5);

    }

    public void add_soda()
    {
        if (amount_bottles == 25)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nLäskbacken är full!");
            Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att gå tillbaka!");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Run();
        }

        Console.Clear();
        //list of different sodas
        content[0] = new Soda("Coca-Cola", 13, "Läsk");
        content[1] = new Soda("Sprite", 10, "Läsk");
        content[2] = new Soda("Fanta", 12, "Läsk");
        content[3] = new Soda("Redbull", 25, "Energidryck");
        content[4] = new Soda("Powerking", 20, "Energidryck");
        content[5] = new Soda("Loka", 14, "Kolsyrat Vatten");
        content[6] = new Soda("Ramlösa", 15, "Kolsyrat Vatten");
        content[7] = new Soda("Spendrups", 15, "Öl");
        content[8] = new Soda("Carlsberg", 17, "Öl");
        content[9] = new Soda("Heineken", 16, "Öl");

        int choice;
        int index = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("\n-=Välj dryck=-     Antal flaskor: [{0}/25]\n", amount_bottles);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,1} {1,10} {2,13} {3,10}", "Index:", "Namn:", "Pris:", "Sort:");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        foreach (var soda in content)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{3,-10} {0,-15} {1,-9} {2}", soda.Name, soda.Price, soda.Type, index++);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\nVälj ett index för att lägga till dryck eller [0] för att avbryta.");

         for (int i = 0; i < sodas.Length; i++)
         {

            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (choice < 0 || choice > 10)
            {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv endast in ett index mellan 1-10 eller 0 för att avbryta!");
            }
            else if (choice == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (i == sodas.Length ) // om läskbacken är full går den tillbaka till Huvudmenyn.
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if (sodas[i] == null)
            {
                sodas[i] = content[choice - 1];
                amount_bottles++;
                Console.WriteLine("Du har lagt till {0}. [{1}/25]", content[choice - 1].Name, amount_bottles);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig inmatning!");
            }
         }


        Console.Clear();

    }

    public void print_crate()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        int index = 1;
        Console.WriteLine("-=Läskbackens innehåll=-      Antal flaskor: [{0}/25]\n ", amount_bottles);
        Console.WriteLine("{0,1} {1,10} {2,13} {3,10}", "Index:", "Namn:", "Pris:", "Sort:");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        foreach (var soda in sodas)
        {
            if (soda != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{3,-10} {0,-15} {1,-9} {2}", soda.Name, soda.Price, soda.Type, index++);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{3,-10} {0,-15} {1,-10} {2}", "Tom Plats", "-" , "-" ,index++);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att gå tillbaka till Huvudmenyn...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }

    public int calc_total()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        int sum = 0;
        foreach (var soda in sodas)
        {
            if (soda != null)
            {
                sum += soda.Price;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Den totala värdet av läskbacken är {0} kronor.\n", sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att gå till Huvudmenyn...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        return sum;
    }

    public void find_soda()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("\n -=Sök efter dryck=-\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Skriv in dryckens namn:");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < sodas.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sodas[i].Name == name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drycken: {0} finns på indexet:{1}\n", sodas[i].Name, i+1);

                Console.WriteLine("[T]Vill du ta bort drycken?");
                Console.WriteLine("[G]å tillbaka till Huvudmenyn");
                string inmatat = Console.ReadLine();
                if (inmatat == "t" || inmatat == "T")
                {
                    amount_bottles--;
                    sodas[i] = null;
                    break;
                }
                else if (inmatat == "g" || inmatat == "G")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (sodas[i].Name != name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drycken hittades inte på indexet: {0}.", i+1);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drycken hittades inte.");
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Tryck på valfri tangent för att gå till Huvudmenyn...");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.SetWindowSize(90, 39);
        var sodacrate = new Sodacrate();
        sodacrate.Run();
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the most minimal amount of code you can. You should find helpful reading how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Well thats correct, an array is fixed, you cant dynamically increase the size of it.
However you can create a new array with a bigger size, copy over the previous values and set the new items equal to the new values.

Your comments seem Swedish which doesn't really help.
However what you probally want to do is rather then removing setting the value to null,
and when adding check if an element is null and set it to its new value. And if none is null copy over the array to a new one with original size+1

```
        int originalSize = 10;
        object[] sodas = new object[originalSize];

        void RemoveSodaAtIndex(int index)
        {
            if(index >= 0 && index < sodas.Length)
            {
                sodas[index] = null;
            }
        }

        void AddSoda(object s)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sodas.Length;i++)
        {
            if(sodas[i]==null)
            {
                sodas[i] = s;
                return;
            }
        }

        originalSize += 1;
        object[] temp = new object[originalSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i != temp.Length - 2)
            {
                temp[i] = sodas[i];
            }
            else
            {
                temp[i] = s;
            }
        }
        sodas = temp;


    }
```